# RxJava 2 causing CalledFromWrongThreadException to be thrown

Tags: android, mvp, rx-java2

Currently trying to mock an api call with RxJava 2 (2.0.6) with delay.
It throws a CalledFromWrongThreadException in my view layer (Activity).

Here is my Observable in my presenter

```
   view.refreshLoadStart();
   Observable.just(createTicketArray(10))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Observer<ArrayList<Ticket>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<Ticket> tickets) {
                    if (getView() != null){
                        view.showTickets(tickets);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (getView() != null){
                        view.refreshLoadComplete();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    if (getView() != null){
                        view.refreshLoadComplete();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is my view methods in my activity

```
    @Override
public void showTickets(final ArrayList<Ticket> tickets) {


//        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter() == null){
        adapter = new TicketAdapter(tickets);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        adapter.setTickets(tickets);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
//            }
//        });

}

@Override
public void refreshLoadComplete() {
//        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    Toast.makeText(TicketActivity.this, "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });
}

@Override
public void refreshLoadStart() {
//        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
//            }
//        });
}
```

Here is the stacktrace of the exception:

```
Process: com.timmccarthy.litt, PID: 22060
                                                                  io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                      at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366)
                                                                      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:62)
                                                                      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8128)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1220)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.requestLayout(RecyclerView.java:3576)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onChanged(RecyclerView.java:4620)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:10448)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:6105)
                                                                      at com.timmccarthy.litt.ui.ticket.TicketActivity.showTickets(TicketActivity.java:82)
                                                                      at com.timmccarthy.litt.ui.ticket.TicketPresenter$1.onNext(TicketPresenter.java:46)
                                                                      at com.timmccarthy.litt.ui.ticket.TicketPresenter$1.onNext(TicketPresenter.java:37)
                                                                      at io.reactivex.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:111)
                                                                      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDelay$DelayObserver$1.run(ObservableDelay.java:84)
                                                                      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
                                                                      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Basically I am asking why is this Exception being thrown since on the Observable I am observing on the main thread and not on another thread?

p.s I did find a fix which is the commented out sections in my code, I just see this as a quick fix and it doesn't really address why I am getting the Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out where I went wrong.

My 'swipetorefresh' listener was calling a refresh method on my presenter which had a separate observable.

Removed this second observable, all the problems went away.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simply actually ,you are modifying views not in the main thread. try this `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`.

does this line gets executed? `Toast.makeText(TicketActivity.this, "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` the commented out sections wont work because you already on the main thread.

Comment: Just tried this out, still throws the same exception as before.

The commented out sections do work, because if you aren't on the main UI thread, it will execute the code in the main UI thread, and if you are already on the main UI thread, it will execute like it normally would.